# Install python 3.7 on top of java image jdk8 image

Tags: java, python, docker, unix, python-3.7

I want to install python 3.7 on top of jdk8 java image.

I am using this but its installing python 3.5. i want to install python 3.7-

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-stretch
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-debian-9/

Comment: Just follow the normal Linux (ubuntu or Debian) install process to get the latest version. See above url

Comment: Its running from last 20min. is there any other solution?

Comment: Depending on what you're doing, two separate images could be a reasonably standard answer to this (one with the Java component and one with the Python component, communicating over HTTP).

Comment: If the automated process does do what you want, you can download Python from the official site and install that.  BTW I have NO clue why you are trying to install Python *over* Java, there is nothing relating these two...